# In CSS animations for SVG, the tag offset-path is currently not support by Safari and Chrome on iOS, what is the alternative

Tags: ios, css, iphone, svg

I am working on a project that required SVG Animations. The SVGs work fine on my Android app, but it does not animate on iOS. I Googled and figured out that offset-path is not supported by Safari and Chrome on iOS. What should I replace the tag with, so it animates like it does on Android?

Here's the link https://caniuse.com/#search=offset-path

Comment: if you need to animate elements along SVG paths you can use SNIL animations or javascript. Can you add an example?

Comment: This project is for a company, and they insist on not using other toolchains. Below is an example of my question offset-path: path('M60,190.5C15,147.5,78,37,254,49.5') and this isn't supported by Safari and Chrome on iOS. Is there a replacement tag for this?

Comment: As I've said: you can use [SMIL animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) - SVG's native animation specification. It also can be done using vanilla javascript.